# Exclude item from ListView sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sorting

I use WPF ListView to display data. I've created data model [used as DataContex for ListView], that contains a member:

```
private CollectionViewSource itemEntryInfosView;
```

ListView's ItemsSource is set to itemEntryInfosView. Let's say, that itemEntryInfosView is filled with data downloaded from database.

To sort data [afer column click] I wrote the following method:

```
    public void SortList_OnExecuting(object parameter)
    {
        var sortColumn = (string)parameter;
        this.itemEntryInfosView.SortDescriptions.Clear();

        if (this.sortAscending)
        {
            this.itemEntryInfosView.SortDescriptions.Add(
                new SortDescription(sortColumn, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            this.sortAscending = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.itemEntryInfosView.SortDescriptions.Add(
                new SortDescription(sortColumn, ListSortDirection.Descending));
            this.sortAscending = true;
        }
    }
```

Let's say that **source** of itemEntryInfoView is ObserverableCollection parameterized by ItemEntry class (simple class with some public properties, ListView defines column for each property)

Everything is working like a chram, but I need to add a feature. I need a special row that represents something like "Add new row". I think that such a row could inherit from ItemEntry. **The row should be excluded from sorting.** (Let's say that should be always at the end of ListView). How can I achieve such a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CompositeCollection`:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Add New" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemEntryInfosView}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to consider a third party control that provides the functionality for you already. For example, the [WPF Extended Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) includes a [DataGrid](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: I'll consider using it if all else fails. I hope there is other solution, I'm afraid I could not have time to replace ListView with DataGrid (hmm, maybe is not so hard?) The second thing - I do not need adding new rows. I used it example to present what need to achieve. In my case I need to execute method (nothing more) that do not affect on current items.

Comment: Consider file manager. Most of them contain "Go folder up" entry at the top of list. I need similar effect. Anyway, CompositeCollection works great in this case.